# how to generate object from variants using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to generate objects from array variants using jquery but i didn't get proper solution for that can anyone help?

here is my HTML code.

```
<table>
<tr class="variants">
    <td>
        100g/
            <input id="100g" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="100g">
        m/
            <input id="m" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="m">
        blue
            <input id="blue" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="blue">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input placeholder="SKU" name="sku" type="text" value="1-3">
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr/>....</tr>
<tr/>....</tr>
```

I need output something like that.

```
{
"100g":{
    "m":{
        "blue":{
            "sku":"1-3",
            "image":"link",
            "price": "9"
        }
    },
    "s":{
        "blue":{
            "sku":"1-3",
            "image":"link",
            "price": "9"
        }
    }
},
"200g":{
    "m":{
        "blue":{
            "sku":"1-3",
            "image":"link",
            "price": "9"
        }
    },
    "s":{
        "blue":{
            "sku":"1-3",
            "image":"link",
            "price": "9"
        }
    }
}}
```

here is fiddle link for more information.
https://jsfiddle.net/fhLqsz3w/

It would be greatly appreciated if someone helped me

Comment: Your desired output is invalid Javascript. You cannot have property names that start with a number. For example: '100g' is not a valid JS variable name.

Comment: sorry for my typo mistake. I just want to store the result in JSON format.

Comment: @bhavinjr, Can you please add whole html for the output that you have shown ?

Comment: @jasmin_makasana can you check here? https://jsfiddle.net/fhLqsz3w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each `tr` of the table. Iterate through all the `input` tag of a row. For all the hidden input, if the key (value is the value of the input element) is present, move to next object otherwise create an object corresponding to that key. For all the non-hidden field, accumulate values in an object accumulator, after exiting the loop, now add the non-hidden object to the original object.

```js
$('#update_btn').click(function(e) {
  var obj = {};
  $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
    var temp = obj;
    var notHidden = {};
    $(this).find('input').each(function(i,e) {
      if(e.type=="hidden"){
        if(!(e.value in temp))
          temp[e.value] = {};
        temp = temp[e.value];
      }
      //added textbox value
      if(e.type!="hidden"){
        notHidden[e.getAttribute('name')] = e.value;
      }
    })
    Object.assign(temp, notHidden);
  });
  console.log(obj);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="variants">
<tbody>
<tr><th> Variant </th> <th> SKU </th><th>Cross Price and Price</th> <th> Qty</th> <th> Image Link/ID </th></tr>
<tr class="variants">
<td>
      100g/                            <input id="100g" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="100g">
m/                            <input id="m" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="m">
blue                            <input id="blue" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="blue">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="SKU" name="sku" type="text" value="1-3">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="Cross Price" step="any" name="cross_price" type="number" value="30.91">
<input placeholder="Price" step="any" name="price" type="number" value="10.3">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="Quantity" step="any" name="qty" type="number" value="">
</td>
<td>
<input name="img" type="text" value="default">
</td>
</tr><tr>
</tr><tr class="variants">
<td>
      100g/                            <input id="100g" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="100g">
s/                            <input id="s" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="s">
blue                            <input id="blue" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="blue">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="SKU" name="sku" type="text" value="1-3">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="Cross Price" step="any" name="cross_price" type="number" value="30.91">
<input placeholder="Price" step="any" name="price" type="number" value="10.3">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="Quantity" step="any" name="qty" type="number" value="">
</td>
<td>
<input name="img" type="text" value="default">
</td>
</tr><tr>
</tr><tr class="variants">
<td>
      200g/                            <input id="200g" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="200g">
m/                            <input id="m" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="m">
blue                            <input id="blue" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="blue">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="SKU" name="sku" type="text" value="1-7">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="Cross Price" step="any" name="cross_price" type="number" value="30.91">
<input placeholder="Price" step="any" name="price" type="number" value="10.3">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="Quantity" step="any" name="qty" type="number" value="">
</td>
<td>
<input name="img" type="text" value="default">
</td>
</tr><tr>
</tr><tr class="variants">
<td>
      200g/                            <input id="200g" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="200g">
s/                            <input id="s" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="s">
blue                            <input id="blue" name="variant_name" type="hidden" value="blue">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="SKU" name="sku" type="text" value="1-7">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="Cross Price" step="any" name="cross_price" type="number" value="30.91">
<input placeholder="Price" step="any" name="price" type="number" value="10.3">
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="Quantity" step="any" name="qty" type="number" value="">
</td>
<td>
<input name="img" type="text" value="default">
</td>
</tr><tr>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
<button id="update_btn">click
</button>
```